# Can we compare the contents of two folders in spotfire?

Tags: unix, spotfire

I have two environments. One is development and another is production. Lets say I have folder in production which has all my metadata like ILs, joins, DS, Analysis, scripts etc. Now in development I have the same folder but with new enhancements done.

Now, I want to compare that what are the changes that have been done and as per the result I will be able to understand the impact.

So, could you please tell me that what is way to compare that two folders of development and production environment?

Comment: Copy (duplicate) your work environment files to your test environment, create a spotfire file where you link both versions, make a link between the tables and link for differences. I'm not aware of easier solution.

Comment: If you want that solution then please adapt the tags of your question,  it's not about spotfire.  What type of trials do you have? UNIX per se may not be able to open them. Also please note that this is not a free code-writing service,  people are supposed to ask specific questions instead of asking for entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the requirements posted here, you can create information link on top of LIB_ITEMS table to fetch details of library item details from Spotfire database. An another set of activity is performed at [this link](http://www.cambridgesoft.com/support/EnterpriseSupport/KnowledgeBase/FAQ/details/Default.aspx?TechNote=2712), but approach can be used for your requirements as well.